# Measure of Dispersion for Labelled Data

Tags: math, statistics

I have data of the form {'A': 5, 'B': 10, 'C': 3} and I'd like to compute a value that's between 0 and 1 for the level of dispersion between labeled data. For example, if all the data were of the form {'A':3}, then there would be no dispersion and the value computed would be 0. If the data were of the form {'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'C': 1}, then the value computed would be 1 because there is maximal dispersion between the labels. And finally if the data were of the form {'A': 1, 'B': 2} then the value computed would be somewhere between 0 and 1.

More specifically, I'm trying to compute a value that indicates the level of physical dispersion between offices. For example, if a team of 10 people are in a single office, then there's no dispersion. If they're in a 10 different offices, then there's maximal dispersion. {'A': 2, 'B': 2, 'C': 2} should have a value less than {'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'C': 1, 'D': 1, 'E': 1, 'F': 1} because the latter is more disperse.

What's the correct mathematical function for this?

Comment: It's not clear what you are looking for; I think it would help if you were more explicit about the problem you face. That said, the one idea that comes to mind is entropy. I can say more if it seems to fit your problem.

Comment: I'm trying to compute a value that indicates the level of physical dispersion between offices. For example, if a team of 10 people are in a single office, then there's no dispersion. If they're in a 10 different offices, then there's maximal dispersion. {'A': 2, 'B': 2, 'C': 2} should have a value less than {'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'C': 1, 'D': 1, 'E': 1, 'F': 1} because the latter is more disperse.

Comment: You could try the entropy. If you label the possible offices as $1$ to $10$ and call $p_i$ the proportion of workers in office $i$ (so $0\le p_i \le 1$ for all $i$), then the entropy score is $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{10}-p_i\log p_i$ (if $p_i=0$, we treat $p_i\log p_i$ as $0$). The higher the entropy value, intuitively, this means more "dispersion".

Comment: The entropy is always non-negative and has value $0$ if all people are in one office, and is maximal when all people are in a different office (i.e. $p_i = 1/10$ for all $i=1,\ldots,10$). This maximal value of the entropy turns out to be $\log 10$, so if you want a score always between $0$ and $1$, you could divide the entropy formula by $\log 10$.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know MathJax doesn't work here. If you copy paste the stuff between the "$" signs into [here](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php), you should see the mathematical symbols render. Anyway, you can search online to get more information/intuitions about entropy. For example, [see here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66186/statistical-interpretation-of-maximum-entropy-distribution).

Comment: Thank you, I think the entropy equation will work nicely especially when divided by  log(team size).